# How to fill DataTable from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have written a stored procedure which gives me result from 3 tables separately. Please have a look on the screenshot.

[image]

`DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];` gives me top result from screenshot, `DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[1];` gives me middle one from screenshot and `ds.Tables[2];` gives me last one.

Now, I want to get all the table information. Please have a look on my code. I am not getting the result.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'race_header' does not belong to
>   table Table2.'

Please provide the solutions for this.

```
public List<ClsStakesRaces> RaceNameDetails(int? Id)
        {
            List<ClsStakesRaces> clsStakes = new List<ClsStakesRaces>();

            SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
            string sSQL;
            sSQL = "exec StakesRacesGetRaceDetails @Id";
            prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            prms[0].Value = Id;
            ds = clsUtilities.CreateCommandwithParams(sSQL, prms);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            dataTable= ds.Tables[1];
            dataTable = ds.Tables[2];
            foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                clsStakes.Add(
                    new ClsStakesRaces
                    {
                        RaceName = Convert.ToString(dr["race_header"]),

                        HorseId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["HorseID"]),
                        Horse = Convert.ToString(dr["Horse"]),
                        Details = Convert.ToString(dr["Details"]),
                        Breeding = Convert.ToString(dr["Breeding"]),
                        Earning = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Earning"]),

                        PreviousWinner = Convert.ToString(dr["PreviousWinners"])
                    });
            }
            return clsStakes;
        }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here and how are these table related to each other ? You do not want to create 3 tables here, the practice is to `JOIN` them into single `TABLE or VIEW` and use that

Comment: @Searching, Actually, I want to retrieve the data from all these 3 tables into a single method. I do not know whether it is achievable or not.

Comment: Can you provide table details, relationships and `StakesRacesGetRaceDetails` contents here? I think you can use `SELECT` with `JOIN` when query executes, or doing merge with same unique ID which exist in all 3 `DataTable`s (note: merging requires exactly same column structure for each `DataTable`).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0]; // actually, forget the new DataTable() bit, changed my mind, point to ds.Tables[0] instead
            dataTable= ds.Tables[1]; // actually, forget ds.Tables[0], point to ds.Tables[1] instead
            dataTable = ds.Tables[2]; // actually, forget ds.Tables[1], point to ds.Tables[2] instead
```

So then

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
```

is actually

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
```

Your third table (`ds.Tables[2]`) doesn't have a column called `race_header`, hence your error.

You probably want to return a single statement based upon a JOIN condition in the SQL stored procedure. If you can't do that for some reason, you will need to iterate each of ds.Tables separately, stitching the objects together in memory.